# Java BufferedReader doesn't load full content of a webpage

Tags: java, url, html, bufferedreader

Hello this is my first question on here and i was wondering if anybody has a solution to my problem, i am trying to get the full content of a webpage after everything has loaded. For example i have a website that pulls information in after the web page has loaded, so like a search page that uses ajax to request data from the server. When i run the code all i get is the basic shell of the webpage and nothing from the search result.

```
    URL url = new URL("a_url");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
```

i am searching pirate bay for torrents, as i am testing the use of magnet downloads in java and when i try to collect the magnet links, and name of the torrent the "inputLine" does not print anything that i have searched for, only what the website consist of before the search has been added. any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: What you are loading is the source of the page. If content is being loaded after the page loads via Javascript that content would not be present in that inputstream.

Comment: Yes i understand that is what it is doing i was hoping for a solution that would be able to wait for the other data to be loaded before returning to the stream to output the data

Answer (score 1):

With your piece, you're requesting the page to the server and displaying to sysout.

Every content pulled after the page is loaded is requested by some javascript. The javascript is interpreted by the Web browser. If you want to have the same result, you should interpret the javascript as the browser does. I think that jsoup has such a feature (never tested).

Other solution : the javascript is accessing the server via a HTTP API. Try to access to the some API from your java code, without requesting the main page.

Comment: i know whats happening but as i said i'm looking for a solution, and as of the other solution i have tried a get method on the webpage to see if the content is driven by php but the same result happens so i do assume it is java script, i did this by using the HttpUrlConnection class if that helps, and thanks for the JSoup idea i will have a look into it